# Dual citizen (US/French) always lived in France and extraterritorial taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, france, marriage

Me, a dutch national living in France since 2005 and my girlfriend, a US and French national are planning to get PACSed (contract of civil union?/married without the religion part ?).

My girlfriend has been living in France all her life but has US citizenship through her US dad.

She is 24 and has never declared US taxes ever.

She is a student and works a small job on the side making about 400 a month but will make a lot more in the near futur with a full-time job.
I however work full-time as a software développer making about 32K a year before tax.

**If we get PACSed, would my income be taxable by the US government?**

Seeing as in France we would be having a joint 'foyer fiscal' (fiscal household?) and the French government can take money from our collective income (this comes with tax reductions hench wanting to get PACSed).